# difference b/w visiting and exploring (dfs)

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

I recently tried to implement dfs in a non-recursive fashion. I came across the fact that there are two separate concepts of **exploring a node** and **visiting a node**. Whats the difference?

And if I keep track of the order in which nodes are explored/visited, what do the respective orders represent?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Depth first search visits each node exactly once, I believe some people may use 'explores' as an alternative term, but in fact 'visits' is more accurate. The order in which nodes are visited by DFS is not defined precisely - if you have multiple children of the current node you may recurse in them in any order, each order resulting in different order of visiting all the nodes. However if you have defined an order of your children(e.g. you store the graph in a neighborhood list), it is more natural to visit the children in this order.

Comment: but in a non recursive dfs, you have to mark the nodes visited as soon as they are pushed on stack!

Comment: yes, otherwise you may visit a node more than once. What problem do you see with that?

Comment: the problem is that in recursive dfs, the nodes are marked in a different fashion. Say I have a graph. Node A has children b,c,d and node b has children e,f. If dfs(recursive) is started from 'a' then nodes are marked visited like a->b->e->f->c->d
But in iterative form, as soon as b, c and d are pushed on stack, they are marked visited.

Comment: Not true. If you visit the nodes like you say in the iterative form you will end up with a BFS, not with a DFS.